# What happened to B'elanna's engineering jacket?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Starting around the beginning of the 4th season of Star Trek Voyager, B'Elanna Torres started wearing an engineering jacket including pocket protector and everything.

At the start of the 5th season, she suddenly stopped wearing it. Why? No longer en vogue?

I'm looking for in universe answers. I knew of the actresses pregnancy.

Comment: I have a veeery vague recollection of something like that said between Paris and B'Elanna, but I just skimmed 5x01 and didn't find it;  I suppose I could be imagining it...

Comment: I'm more interested in the pocket protector. Are we really to believe that 24th century sartorial engineers have not yet developed the self-protecting pocket?!?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The jacket was created to help cover actress Roxann Dawson's pregnancy.  Here's a link that mentions it, though it's not really from an authoritative source: http://voyagerview.com/roxann.html

As I understand it, pregnancies only last so long, at which point the jacket was no longer required.

To give a mildly in-universe answer, she also wore it due to her in-universe pregnancy, starting in Q2 (as stated in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_trek_uniforms)

Comment: This is essentially correct; they kept it the entire season so that dropping it wouldn't look weird, and a bit of trivia: in [The Killing Game](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Killing_Game_(episode)), that's her real pregnancy onscreen, not padding.

Comment: +1 for `As I understand it, pregnancies only last so long...`

Comment: @Tacroy however read "Excession" by Iain M Banks for a counterexample :)